# I’m having trouble converting this orthogonal shape to isometric, I’m only a beginner and would really appreciate some help

Tags: modeling

Orthogonal to isometric shape, I need help with this as I’m only a beginner, please help me.

[image: drawing]

Comment: Please describe to us where you are stuck as well as your progress so far. This appears to be a [homework](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/what-should-our-position-be-on-homework-type-questions) question.

Comment: When you ask stuff like this be aware that there are 2 projection rules. So you should specify what projection rule you use, if you dont know atleast specify country so we can guess. But yeah looks like third angle projection. Anyway what bothers me is why use hidden line in one place and not another

Comment: There are many books that show the process, here is but one: https://www.amazon.com/Basic-Technical-Drawing-Henry-Spencer/dp/0022321500

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Now can you draw it?

Post your attempt in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my effort, you should be able to finish it up.

[image]

You can start with something simple:

[image]